# auto-shuffle divs every n seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here my code for random divs with the same class name. Now all I need is to keep randomizing them every n seconds (15 seconds for instance) without the need to refresh the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/yxBhH/

JS code:

```
var parent = $("#shuffle");
var divs = parent.children();
while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it? I'm still not used to javascript yet so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` function:

```js
var $parent = $("#shuffle");
var $divs = $parent.children();

setInterval(function() {
  var $clone = $divs.slice();
  while ($clone.length) {
    $parent.append($clone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * $clone.length), 1));
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.hue {
  background: #ddd;
}

.hue:nth-child(2n) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shuffle">
  <div class="hue">one</div>
  <div class="hue">two</div>
  <div class="hue">three</div>
  <div class="hue">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I am actually familiar with setTimeout but not this method. thanks again!

Comment: How to make this shuffle and only show 2 elements ( for example ) ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881128/shuffle-divs-but-show-limited-number-of-them/42881216