# shuffle divs but show limited number of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code to shuffle elements of div every n seconds .. is there a way to display only 2 elements (for example ) with each shuffle ?

```
var parent = $("#shuffle");
var divs = parent.children().slice();

setInterval(function() {
    var clone = divs.slice(); // <-- clone, since splice modifies array
    while (clone.length) {
        parent.append(clone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * clone.length), 1)[0]);
    }
}, 2000); // <-- shuffle each 2 seconds
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yxBhH/1/
I'm Interested in Javascript solution

Comment: What does "only n number of elements" mean in practice? You only have four elements on the page, do you want to limit it to e.g. two?

Comment: Yes , I want to show 2 elements for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy solution.

On each interval, clear out all of the elements, and then add `n` elements randomly picked from the list.

```
var populateParent = (function() {
  var parent = $("#shuffle");
  var divs = parent.children().slice();
  return function() {
    parent.empty();
    var clone = divs.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2 && i < divs.length; ++i) {
      parent.append(clone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * clone.length), 1)[0]);
    };
  }
})();

populateParent();
setInterval(populateParent, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rv7zpd07/5/

Comment: Just on issue , when it initiates .. all elements are displayed

Comment: @KamalSaleh If that's an issue, you can call `parent.empty()` before the initial call to `setInterval()`

Comment: I already tried it but it initiates empty .. this is important because my interval will be 15 seconds .. so it will be empty for 15 seconds .

Comment: @KamalSaleh Did you call `parent.empty()` __after__ `parent.children().slice()`? http://jsfiddle.net/rv7zpd07/4/

Comment: Yes , and it starts empty until first interval pass

Comment: @KamalSaleh If you want it to be called first as well, move the population code into a separate function and call it first. I've updated my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of `div`s displayed using another `:nth-child` CSS rule. If you want to display only two, for example, you would use:

```
.hue:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
var parent = $("#shuffle");
var divs = parent.children().slice();

setInterval(function() {
    var clone = divs.slice();
    while (clone.length) {
        parent.append(clone.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * clone.length), 1)[0]);
    }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.hue {
    background: #ddd;
    display: block;
}
.hue:nth-child(2n) {
    background: yellow;
    display: block;
}

.hue:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shuffle">
    <div class="hue">one</div>
    <div class="hue">two</div>
    <div class="hue">three</div>
    <div class="hue">four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm interested in JavaScript solution because I have to display many containers in one page which each will have it's defined length

Comment: You could give each container its own id and then use the CSS above on a per-element basis.